# QT: Creating different QGraphicsItems from one slot

Tags: c++, qt

I have some classes inherited from QGraphicsItem, I also have buttons in my interface. Right now, when I press a button, an item is created in the scene. I have such signal/slot system for all of my classes, so as a result I have a lot of slot functions that are very similar, and the only difference is in the type of objects they create. Is this a good programming practice or not, because it doesn't look like it. Is there a way to simplify this?

Armchair is a class inherited from QGraphicsItem
armchair is an object of this class
this is a code example of such slot function

```cpp
void MainWindow::armchairButton_clicked()
{
    scene_preview->clear();
    armchair = new Armchair();
    scene_preview->addItem(armchair);
}
```

Comment: The function could be implemented as a template function. (...I guess as you didn't expose any source code.)

Comment: I edited my question, please have a look @Scheff'sCat

Comment: Are you using Qt Designer for the UI and use the auto-wire feature (connect slots by name), or do you manually connect the signals and slots via a connect call?

Comment: @king_nak I manually connected these slots

Answer (score 0):

There is no general fixed rule for this, just the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself).

In general, every button has a distinct function, so there must be some code to distinguish those.

Depending on how much code is common and how much is individual, you need to find a good balance.

In your case, you seem to only have 1 thing to change (the object type to add) and some common code for cleaning. This could be separated, e.g.

```
void MainWindow::replaceSceneObject(QGraphicsItem *i)
{
    scene_preview->clear();
    scene_preview->addItem(i);
}

void MainWindow::armchairButton_clicked()
{
    replaceSceneObject(new Armchair);
}
```

As you use manual connects, you actually don't need separate slots for this, but could use lambdas in the connect calls, e.g.:

```
connect(armchairButton, &QPushButton:clicked, [=]{ replaceSceneObject(new Armchair); });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! So, you placed the lines for clearing and creation into a separate function, but I would still need to have a separate slot for every button to call that function, right? This looks like a better design, thank you.

Comment: Well, with the lambda connect call, you don't need a slot. You just call the function there